# Cannot Run Query in Parallel Plesk v12

Tags: sql-server, plesk

In Parallel Plesk 12, after i click the "Run Query" button there is nothing happen but page refresh like in below figure :

[image]

After Parallel Plesk upgrade from v10 to v12, all of my database is cannot be opened from Parallel Plesk itself.

Help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I just delete all of "go" words, i generate my database query from Sybase Power Designer which included "go" words in queries. In below figure, there are some process that need several seconds which i red circled :

[image]